# Gitlab CI runner

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have used [this tutorial](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/docker.md) for setting up a gitlab ci runner. The runner seems to be working. Now I want to build a C++ project with it.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you wanna stick with Docker Runners (no shell), some examples are provided [here](http://quaintous.com/2016/08/12/test-and-code-coverage-with-gitlab-ci/) (*disclaimer*: article is by me!)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have a shell runner, you can create a job and list the command line commands you want to have executed. Create a file `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the root directory of your git repository:

```
my_project:
  script:
    - cd apps/my_project
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make
```

When you push, and ci runners are enabled on gitlab, it will automatically execute all these shell commands for each push.

More information about the things you can put into `.gitlab-ci.yml` can be found [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html).